# How can I periodically end-to-end test Xamarin iOS and Android apps?

Tags: android, ios, testing, xamarin, end-to-end

I've have iOS and Android Xamarin apps (*not* Forms). They call into backend services.

I'd like to set up some automated testing that runs periodically (one a day, say) where I can simulate text entry and clicks and make sure the correct result is returned in an output field.

I don't want to have to launch this. It needs to be fully automated and alert me on failure.

Are there services/products that support this? Happy to use commercial services.

I'm aware of products like Test Cloud, but not sure if I can set up a simple periodic end-to-end test like the one I described.

@Joe Lv Think of it this way. At present, each morning, I launch the app, enter some text, press OK and then look at the info on the screen that is returned. I'd like to automated exactly that task---so I never have to look at the app again (hopefully). If the results are unexpected, then I want to receive an alert.

Comment: Hi, I can't understand your question? Are there any App which has the function which you have described? In Android, I think maybe you are talking about [monkey](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/monkey.html)? But maybe it can't run periodically. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @Joe Lv. See my edit above.

Comment: First, you can't keep your app alive all the time on Android system, so your demand can't be achieved. If you have a rooted phone, it will be achieved.